# 404 error using telerik RadCaptcha on Windows 2008R2 on IIS7.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I am using telerik to show the capcha image. It was working in Windows 2003 server on IIS6 now It is now working in Wondows 2008R2 server with IIS7.5. I Image is not coming . After looking on fiddler I found it is showing 404 error code.

here is the Aspx part

```
    <telerik:RadCaptcha ID="RadCaptcha1"   Runat="server" ErrorMessage="The code you entered is not valid." ForeColor="Red"
                                     CaptchaImage-BackgroundColor="#4c669F" CaptchaImage-TextColor="White" ValidationGroup="Group"
                                     CaptchaTextBoxCssClass="employee" CaptchaTextBoxLabel="&nbsp; Type the code from the image" ImageStorageLocation="Session"/>

and web config settings

<system.webServer>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
            <add name="RadUploadModule" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadHttpModule, Telerik.Web.UI" preCondition="managedHandler" />
        </modules>
        <handlers>
            <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
            <add name="ChartImage.axd_*" path="ChartImage.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler, Telerik.Web.UI, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4" preCondition="integratedMode" />
            <add name="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd_*" path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler, Telerik.Web.UI, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4" preCondition="integratedMode" />
            <add name="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx_*" path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler, Telerik.Web.UI, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4" preCondition="integratedMode" />
            <add name="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx_*" path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.Upload.RadUploadProgressHandler, Telerik.Web.UI" preCondition="integratedMode" />
            <add name="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd_*" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource, Telerik.Web.UI"  preCondition="integratedMode" />         
            <!--<add name="ChartImageWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="ChartImage.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler, Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2012.1.411.40, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4"/>
            <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResourceSession" />--> <!--captcha-->
        </handlers>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <clear/>
                <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=8"/>
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
         <security>
          <requestFiltering>
             <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
          </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
```

and

```
<httpHandlers>
            <add verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
            <add path="ChartImage.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler, Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2012.1.411.40, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4" validate="false"/>
            <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResourceSession" verb="*" validate="false" /><!--captcha-->
        </httpHandlers>
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Try with these handler definitions:

```
    <handlers>

        <remove name="ChartImage_axd" />
        <add name="ChartImage_axd" path="ChartImage.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
        <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_SpellCheckHandler_axd" />
        <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_SpellCheckHandler_axd" path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
        <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_aspx" />
        <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_aspx" path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
        <remove name="Telerik_RadUploadProgressHandler_ashx" />
        <add name="Telerik_RadUploadProgressHandler_ashx" path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadProgressHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
        <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" />
        <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
```

and

```
    <httpHandlers>
        <add path="ChartImage.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler" verb="*" validate="false" />
        <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler" verb="*" validate="false" />
        <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" verb="*" validate="false" />
        <add path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadProgressHandler" verb="*" validate="false" />
        <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
```

If this does not help - try using a SessionWebResource handler, especially if you have a farm of servers: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/captcha-webfarm-and-webgarden.html

```
<add path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResourceSession, Telerik.Web.UI" verb="*" validate="false" />
```

and

```
<add name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResourceSession, Telerik.Web.UI" />
```